# How to execute a dynamic case when in np.where and create a new column in pandas dataframe just like pyspark with column expr?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to pass dynamically generated strings into np.where that needs to be evaluated as a condition.

```
condtion1 = "(df['topicA'] == 1) & (df['topicA:subtopic1'] ==0) & (df['topicA:subtopic2'] ==0) & (df['topicB'] ==0), 1, 0"
condtion2 = "(df['topicA'] == 1) & (df['topicA:subtopic1'] ==1) & (df['topicA:subtopic2'] ==0) & (df['topicB'] ==0), 1, 0"
condtion3 = "(df['topicB'] == 1) & (df['topicB:subtopic1'] ==0), 1, 0"


df['topicA - generic'] = np.where(condition1)
df['topicA - subtopic1'] = np.where(condition2)
df['topicB - generic'] = np.where(condition3)
```

Is there a way to achieve this? My condition strings could have any number of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.

First, replace the statement below with a string object.
It would be convenient to use Formatting at this time.

```
case1 = f"df['topicA - generic'] = np.where({condition1})"
case2 = f"df['topicA - subtopic1'] = np.where({condition2})"
case3 = f"df['topicB - generic'] = np.where({condition3})"
```

Then you run it using the exec() function.

```
exec(case1)
exec(case2)
exec(case3)
```

It's simple, right?